# Higgs mechanism to break $E_8$ down to $SU(8)$?

Tags: higgs, lie-algebra, symmetry-breaking

Say you had the group $E_8$ and you wanted to break it down to $SU(8)$ via a Higgs symmetry breaking potential. Is this possible? (We know it is a subgroup at least since $E_8$ contains $O(16)$).

For example it is fairly straight forward to break down a group $SU(5)$ into $SU(2)\times SU(3)\times U(1)$ with a diagonal Higgs matrix $(2,2,2,-3,-3)$.

But I'm not sure how you would do it say with $E_8$ down to $SU(8)\times U(1)$ for example?

I guess you would find a generator that is invariant under $SU(8)$ but not under $E_8$ ?

Comment: [Slansky](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.1581&rep=rep1&type=pdf), Table 53 does $E_8\to SU(9)$.

Comment: @Cosmas Nice resource.